# LibreOffice - Mutli page pdf gets converted to single page docx file

Tags: pdf, docx, libreoffice

I am trying to convert a PDF file to docx using command line using:

```
soffice --infilter=“writer_pdf_import” --convert-to “docx:MS Word 2007 XML” *.pdf
```

The Input PDF contains multiple pages.
The Output Docx file when opened has the contents of the pages over written onto one another into a single page. Hence, the number of pages in the Docx file is only 1.

Section of the document is shown in the Image below.

I expect each page on PDF written to corrosponding page in Docx.

**Additional Info:**

Version: LibreOffice 7.5.4.2 36ccfdc35048b057fd9854c757a8b67ec53977b6

OS: Windows

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with Libreoffice 7.5.2.2 and 7.5.5.2.

Solved by uninstalling Libreoffice 7 and installing LibreOffice 6.4.7.2.
This command now works wihtout collapsing:

soffice --convert-to "docx:MS Word 2007 XML" "source_path_to.pdf" --outdir target_folder --infilter="writer_pdf_import" --headless

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a bug in newer versions: https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=156303

Temporary workaround: use LibreOffice 7.4.3.2 - the last correctly working version.