# Convert a Multi-Page Text/word file to PNG using LibreOffice API in JAVA

Tags: java, sdk, libreoffice, openoffice.org, libreoffice-writer

How to convert a Multi-Page Text file to PNG, for example:- I have a Text document of 5 pages and I want to convert that into PNG. By default, it's giving a PNG of only 1st page. How to get the PNG file for ith page using LibreOffice.

I used the PageRange filter like this, but it does not work, it's also giving the PNG only for 1st page.

Also, I'm not able to generate multiple PNGs for multi-page word files using the LibreOffice Application

CLI:-

```
soffice --convert-to 'png:writer_png_Export:{"PageRange":{"type":"string","value":"2-"}}' test.odt
```

JAVA:-

```
conversionProperties[0] = new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue();
conversionProperties[0].Name = "FilterName";
conversionProperties[0].Value ="writer_png_Export";

conversionProperties[1] = new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue();
conversionProperties[1].Name = "PageRange";
conversionProperties[1].Value ="2-";
```

I found a similar link on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76738992/libreoffice-mutli-page-pdf-gets-converted-to-single-page-docx-file), but it also gives PNG for 1st page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

someone from LibreOffice has confirmed that this feature is not supported currently.

Ref: https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=157425